# Having trouble creating a list based on function arguments

Tags: r, list, function

I am trying to create a function, in which a named list is created (I need to use this specific structure, as it is required to call a downstream function). However, despite the name being defined as an argument of the function, it is not being carried through. Here is a minimal example:

```
make_list = function(first, second){
  return(list(first=second))
}
make_list("name", "value")
#$`first`
#[1] "value"
```

Note the name "first", rather than "name". First was intended to just be an argument in the function, but it is not being used as such. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Hey markus. You are obviously more involved than I am on stack exchange, so I imagine your edit is the correct way to go. But I am a little confused. In my original, it was clear that this was a console output, with those latter bits being the output. But now, don't they look like comments?

Comment: This way it is easier to copy&paste your code.

Comment: And that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the declaration of `list(first=second)`, the "`first`" is the attribute name but not the variable `first`.

```
make_list = function(first, second){
  ret = list()
  ret[[first]] = second
  return(ret)
}
make_list("name", "value")
#$name
#[1] "value"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in one line using `setNames`.

```
make_list <- function(first, second) {
    setNames(list(second), first)
}

make_list("name", "value")
# $name
# [1] "value"
```